# Conditions for a block matrix to be positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, positive-definite, semidefinite-programming

Consider the block matrix given by
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}&A_{12}&0\\ 
A_{12}&A_{22}&A_{23}\\
0&A_{23}&A_{33}\end{bmatrix}$$

What conditions should I impose on each matrix $A_{ij}$ to ensure that M is positive definite? Each matrix $A_{ij}$ is symmetric. I would like not to use a Schur complement-like condition to avoid deal with inverses. Also, could someone provide a good reference on this subject?

Thank you

Comment: If $M$ is PD, its principal submatrices have to be PD too. So, the first question that you should ask yourself is: how to decide whether $\pmatrix{A_{11}&A_{12}\\ A_{12}&A_{22}}$ is PD without using Schur complements?

Comment: Actually, my question was the opposite. Formulating in terms of the principal submatrices would be like this. What are the conditions over the principal submatrices for which M is PD? Showing that these submatrices are PD is enough?

Comment: $\left(\begin{array}{c} A &  X \\ X^* & B \end{array}\right)$ is positive iff $X=A^{1/2}K B^{1/2}$ where $K$ is a contraction

Comment: How do you define a contraction?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the post by user1551, I came up with the following proof.

If each matrix $A_{ij}$ is such that the block submatrices

\begin{equation*}
M_1=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11}&A_{12}\\
A_{12}&A_{22}/2
\end{bmatrix},
M_2=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{22}/2&A_{23}\\
A_{23}&A_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
is positive definite, then the matrix $M$ is positive definite.

Proof. By assumption $M_1$ and $M_2$ are positive definite. Consequently, for vectors $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ the following inequalities hold
\begin{align*}
x^\top A_{11}x + x^\top A_{12}y + y^\top A_{12} x + y^\top \dfrac{A_{22}}{2} y&>0\\
y^\top \dfrac{A_{22}}{2}y + y^\top A_{23}z + z^\top A_{23} y + z^\top A_{33} z&>0
\end{align*}
Summing both equations yields
\begin{equation}
x^\top A_{11}x + x^\top A_{12}y + y^\top A_{12} x + y^\top A_{22}y+y^\top A_{23}z + z^\top A_{23} y + z^\top A_{33} z>0.
\end{equation}
This inequality implies that the matrix $M$ is positive definite.